# How does the inner function parameter is being passed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am reading article about angular form. One of the snippet show higher order function. I am really confuse when there are parameters inside the inner function, but the argument is never passed to the function. How does the valuechanges parameter being passed actually? The article is here 
Here's [the link](https://netbasal.com/detect-unsaved-changes-in-angular-forms-75fd8f5f1fa6)!

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isDirty$ = this.settings.valueChanges.pipe(
      dirtyCheck(store$),
    );

  }
```

```
export function dirtyCheck<U>(source: Observable<U>) {
  return function<T>(valueChanges: Observable<T>): Observable<boolean> {

    const isDirty$ = combineLatest(
      source,
      valueChanges,
    ).pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      map(([a, b]) => isEqual(a, b) === false),
      startWith(false),
    );

    return isDirty$;
  };
}
```

Comment: The `pipe` function would do that, e.g. `x.pipe(y)` is roughly equivalent to `y(x)`.

Comment: What the keyword for a good reading about this topic? It takes me long time to understand this

Comment: See [Pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). Note that the name `pipe` itself is a reference to similar operators in a variety of functional languages, e.g. [elixir](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/pipe-operator/), [f#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/index#function-composition-and-pipelining), and as a proposed addition to [js](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator)

Comment: Are you talking about Rxjs ? If yes then here are few sites [Learn Rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) and [Rxjs Docs](https://rxjs.dev/)

Comment: Perhaps I am not clear how higher order function works in the first place